# aws tcp not flowing thru vpc peering (udp does)

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp

I have 2 VPCs on AWS that are peered and is associated with a route table that has:

```
Destination | Target | Status
10.1.0.0/16 | local | Active
0.0.0.0/0 | nat-xxxxx | Active
10.3.0.0/16 | pcx-xxxxx | Active
```

This route table is associated with a subnet in `10.1.0.0/16` that has an instance whose's security group allows outbound `55554/tcp`

In the second vpc `10.3.0.0/16`, the route table associated with the subnet is:

```
10.3.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0 igw-4790a12e
```

This VPC will only accept logs from `10.1.0.0/16`.
There is an instance in this subnet with a security group that accepts incoming `55554/tcp` from `10.1.0.0/16`.

This connection is not going thru. When I change the same with `55555/udp`, I can see the data being transferred.

Comment: Aren't you going to need a route from the 10.3 network back to the 10.1 network via the peering connection? As it stands, your default route is the IGW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a route table entry for the VPC 10.3.0.0/16 with a pcx-xxxxxx route.

The reason that UDP works is that 10.1.0.x can send to 10.3.0.x and a reply is NOT required. But for 10.1.0.x to connect to 10.3.0.x a route has to be defined in both route tables so that a return response that creates the connection can be made.